# nested do while not .eof loop based on select query access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am basically trying to convert vertical data to horizontal (like an excel table) an am almost there. I have to use a nested loop but not sure how to go about it! Here's the code so far which is working but not how I want:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblTimeSheetData WHERE [WorkDate] BETWEEN #" & 
StartDate & "# AND #" & EndDate & "#" _ 
  & "ORDER BY [EmpID], [WorkDate] ;"    

Set rstTime = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)   

Do While Not rstTime.EOF    
    rstTemp.AddNew
    lngEmpID = rstTime![EmpID]
    rstTemp![EmpID] = lngEmpID

    intWeekday = Weekday(rstTime![WorkDate])

    Select Case intWeekday

        Case 2
           rstTemp![MondayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![MondayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 3
           rstTemp![TuesdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![TuesdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 4
           rstTemp![WednesdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![WednesdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 5
           rstTemp![ThursdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![ThursdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 6
           rstTemp![FridayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![FridayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

     End Select

     rstTemp.Update
     rstTime.MoveNext
  Loop
```

My select query returns exactly what I want:
[Select query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNgef.jpg)

My code returns this:
[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfxe8.jpg)

I want it to return this:
[Horizontal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlmt2.jpg)

Thank you.
AG

Comment: `rstTemp.AddNew` you should only do this when the employee id is different from the previous one.

Comment: I suggest using a Crosstab query (PIVOT) instead. This is exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

You should only add a new record when the employee id is different from the previous one:

```
Dim currEID As Long 'tracks the current employee id

'...


currEID = -1

Do While Not rstTime.EOF

    lngEmpID = rstTime![EmpID]

    'new employee?  If yes then add a new record
    If currEID <> lngEmpID Then
        rstTemp.AddNew
        rstTemp![EmpID] = lngEmpID
        currEID = lngEmpID
    End If

    intWeekday = Weekday(rstTime![WorkDate])

    Select Case intWeekday

     '....rest of select case here

    End Select

    rstTime.MoveNext
Loop

rstTemp.UpdateBatch
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Great idea however, when it hits the second set of dates it gives an error because there is no addnew, since it's inside the If statement. When I take the addnew right before the If statement then I get sth very similar to what I used to get (5 rows again instead of 2), just that the names are not repeated! I am pretty sure it has to be another loop but how?!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment.  However you should be able to see the general approach.  Another change would be to move the Update outsude of the loop and use UpdateBatch at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!! It did need a nested loop. Instead of one query to bring the total records (5) I did two queries (2 then 3 and 2) within the nested loops as seen below and that did the trick. Thanks.

```
Set rstTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTimeSheetDataTemp")
Set rstTime = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTimeSheetData")

'this next query finds two distinct records John and Helen's EmpID
strSqla = "SELECT DISTINCT tblTimeSheetData.EmpID FROM tblTimeSheetData 
WHERE [WorkDate] BETWEEN #" & StartDate & "# AND #" & EndDate & "#"

Set rstCts = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSqla, dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rstCts.EOF

  lngEmpID = rstCts![EmpID]
  rstTemp.AddNew

  'This next query finds the number of records with John's (or Helen's) 
  'EmpIDs between Start and End dates
  strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblTimeSheetData WHERE [EmpID] = " & lngEmpID & " 
AND [WorkDate] BETWEEN #" & StartDate & "# AND #" & EndDate & "#"
  Set rstTime = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)

  Do While Not rstTime.EOF

     rstTemp![EmpID] = lngEmpID

     intWeekday = Weekday(rstTime![WorkDate])

     Select Case intWeekday

        Case 2
           rstTemp![MondayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![MondayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 3
           rstTemp![TuesdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![TuesdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 4
           rstTemp![WednesdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![WednesdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 5
           rstTemp![ThursdayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![ThursdayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

        Case 6
           rstTemp![FridayWorkDate] = rstTime![WorkDate]
           rstTemp![FridayWorkHours] = rstTime![WorkHours]

     End Select
  rstTime.MoveNext
  Loop

rstTemp.Update
rstCts.MoveNext

Loop
```